# Cordova Windows10 app not able to call custom plugin with WinRT

Tags: cordova, uwp, windows-runtime, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use a custom plugin in my Cordova Windows 10 application. The plugin has a Windows Runtime Component and a dll. The app is throwing a runtime error 'WinRT: unknown runtime error'. Any idea what could be the issue?

```
 Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x05FB7264.

Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

onecore\com\combase\objact\dllcache.cxx(4713)\combase.dll!76EE8582: (caller: 76EEF9EB) ReturnHr(1) tid(5444) 80131040 onecoreuap\inetcore\lib\scriptprojectionhost\scripthostcontext.cxx(455)\edgehtml.dll!7B61BDA1: (caller: 78996D5E) LogHr(28) tid(5444) 80131040 Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptException at memory location 0x05FBB3D8.

Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptException at memory location 0x05FBB6B0.

Exception thrown at 0x77834402 in WWAHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptException at memory location 0x05FBB930.

Script info: CONSOLE6000 Exception calling native with command :: LoginPlugin :: login ::exception=WinRTError: Unknown runtime error (~21572)
```

Comment: Can you share a simple repro?

Comment: Hi Peter here is the repo link https://github.com/TarakKar/cordova-uwp-plugin-sample.git. I have also updated the README content with the steps to get it running. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a simple repro that doesn't rely on npm etc? A simple WWA that calls your C# API, for example. Is the DLL in your AppX package?